# Is int b; declaration for an integer number or for a field ( and understandig the meaning of: "directly inside the class" )

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a differences between declarations to define an integer numbers and declarations for a fields. 
EXAMPLE: Declaration 'int b;' can be declaration for the inetger number b or it can be the declaration for the private field b. As it looks like, it depends on where this declaration is situated.

I know, that typical declaration to define a field is 'private string field;'

In the code below in the class MyClass I can't declare the integer numbers, but just the fields. Why?
I wrote 'int b;' because I wanted to declare the integer number b, but I got the field b. Visual Studio shows me, that 'b' is the field.

```
using System;
class MyClass
{
   int b;

   public static int x = 20;   
   public static int y;
   public static int z = 25;

   public MyClass(int i)
   {
      x = i;
      y = i;
      z = i;
   }
}

class MyClient
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
      MyClass mc = new MyClass(25);
      Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is based on scope - a variable declared in the scope of MyClass is a field of that class. A variable declared in the scope of a method is a variable local to that method. Note that your example `int b = 7` is functionally equivalent to `private int b = 7`, since it will get the access modifier `private` by default.

Comment: agree with E. Moffat

Comment: @E. Moffat  I'm reading about scopes, but I can't understand it at the moment. Why is a variable declared in the scope of MyClass a field of that class? This class is ordinary class, isn't it? Also if I delete everything inside class, b still remains field. Are in this scope just fields available and how this can be changed?

Comment: @prahsC take a look at my updated answer, I've added some replacement code for you. Hopefully, it will help.

Comment: @prahsC See EJoshuaS answer. The concept of scope is a basic programming topic that should be explained in just about any intro course, probably in a much better way than I could explain it. Svek's answer is correct but it is unclear from your question if that is what you were asking

Answer (score 2):

All fields are variables, but not all variables are fields.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx),

> A field is a variable of any type that is declared directly in a class or struct. Fields are members of their containing type.

Or, more simply, fields are variables that are associated only with the class or object itself, *not* with a specific method.

Thus, when you have `int b = 7;`, it is technically correct to call it a variable, but it's more specific to call it a field. It's the same way that it's technically correct to simply call a Porsche Boxter a car - it *is*, in fact, a car, but it's more descriptive (and, therefore, potentially more useful) to call it a Boxter.

Note in particular that the definition of a field says absolutely nothing about what else is included in the class. A field is a field regardless of what other content you do (or don't) have in the class (so, for example, the fact that `MyClass` doesn't have a `Main` method is completely irrelevant).

Fields can be distinguished from a local variable, which is declared inside a method and is associated only with that particular method. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
   public int a = 10; // This is a field
   int b = 20; // Also a field

   public void MyMethod() {
      int c = 30; // This is a local variable, NOT a field
   }
}
```

Note, in particular, that `c` is *not* "declared directly in a class or struct" - it's declared inside a method. Thus, by definition it's not a field.

Comment: @prahsC My point is that "field" and "variable" are not mutually exclusive - a field is a type of variable in much the same way that a Porsche Boxter is a type of car.

Comment: @prahsC Can you clarify what follow-up you're requesting for that particular code sample?

Comment: I understand you, but Visual Studio shows me in the code below, that the variables are local var., but they're fields also.
In the code from the begining of this question the Visual Studio shows, that var. are fields. Is it just the question of the compiler or editor?

using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 2;
                     
            Console.WriteLine("Value of a is  " + a + ".");
            Console.ReadLine();
           
        }
    }
}

Comment: In the example you give, `a` is definitely **not** a field if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes it is, I uderstand you, but in the last code declaration for 'a' is inside a class, so 'a' should be a field, as you wrote before, but is not.

Comment: @prahsC The key word in the definition is "declared **directly** inside the class." `a` in your method isn't declared directly in the class, it's declared in a method. Obviously that method's part of the class, but in C# *all* executable code is inside a class, so that's beside the point.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and now I can see: if I declare variable inside the class, but not inside the method, the variable is field.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wording in your question, I feel that your understanding of using the words "variables" and "field" is misguided.

You seem to be calling:

- "variables" as `private` fields
- "fields" as `public` fields

Take a look at the below code block, to help:

```
class MyClass
{
    int b = 7; // this is a private field
    private int c = 8; // this is a private field

    public int d = 10; // this is a public field
}
```

In addition, from the code above, you can now understand the reason why you are unable to access `b`. It is due to the `private` access modifier that is assumed. You need to change it to a `public` field.

---

So, what you'll want to get your code up and going quickly is change:

> ```
> int b = 7;
> ```

to

```
public int b = 7;
```

and then you can change

> ```
> public static void Main()
> {
>    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
>    MyClass mc = new MyClass(25);
>    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
>    Console.ReadLine();
> }
> ```

to

```
public static void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
   MyClass mc = new MyClass(25);
   Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyClass.x, MyClass.y, MyClass.z);
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", mc.b);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

*Take special note that public fields should usually be avoided in favor for [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can read more about that by doing a few searches online.*

---

### Additional Resources

- [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)
- [static (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)
- [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)